# Alter properties of objects in a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have declared a variable in my main html page as such:

```
var ColorBuffer;
```

I pass this variable into a function:

```
myFunc("example.txt", ColorBuffer);
```

Within this function a property of the variable is set as shown:

```
function myFunc(file, colBuf)
{
    ...

    colBuf.items = 4;
}
```

However when I refer to 'ColorBuffer.items' within my main html page I get the error 'Cannot read property 'items' of undefined'.

So it seems that using the parameter name colBuf does not affect the argument ColorBuffer passed in...how could I set the items property of ColorBuffer from within my function?

Many thanks.

Comment: You forgot to give your variable a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting ColorBuffer as an object will resolve this.

```
var ColorBuffer = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is undefined because it has no value. What will the variable be, an array? String? Plain Object?

Whatever it may be, give it a basic value:

```
var ColorBuffer = {}; //For object
var ColorBuffer = 0; //For number
var ColorBuffer = []; //For array
//etc etc
```